# FragmentContainerView with SupportMapFragment crashes when minify is enabled

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx

I have the following layout:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".map.MapActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

It works fine with my debug build, but my release build with minify enabled crashes.

```
09-04 15:14:06.727 15555 15555 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
09-04 15:14:06.727 15555 15555 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
09-04 15:14:06.727 15555 15555 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$c: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it? If I replace the `FragmentContainerView` with the old fragment view, it works.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with appcompat version 1.2.0 (I saw this crash after upping to 1.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to minification. If you have minify enabled, you probably have to add something similar to this to your proguard:
`-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in aapt2, and is being tracked in a bug by google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142601969

In the meantime, the easiest way to fix this is to add `@Keep` to any fragments that you use in this manner.

If it's a fragment from a library where you are unable to modify the code, you can add it as a rule in your `proguard.cfg`:

`-keep class om.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }`

Comment: You don't need to manually keep the whole google maps library. You only need to keep the SupportMapFragment constructor.